# extract a result/variable from a function in R

Tags: r, function

I create a function to do some data analysis on variables on my dataset. The function calculates `diff` for each variable. I want to extract each`diff`, then created a vector `vdiff` consists of all `diff`

```
var = function(dt, title){
  m=count(dt)
  vlist=list()
  for (i in (1:dim(m)[1])){
    m$"%Renew"[i]=sum(data$Renew==1 & dt ==m$x[i])/m$freq[i] *100
  }

  diff=max(m[,3]) - min(m[,3])
  vlist=list(table=m, difference = diff)

  ggplot(m, aes(x,m[,3])) + geom_point()+
          theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1), axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold")) +
          labs(x=title, y="% Renew") + ylim(0,100)
}


var(data$Product, "Product")
var(data$Purchase, "Purchase")
var(data$Type, "Type")
var(data$Freq, "Freq")
var(data$Gender, "Gender")
var(data$State, "State")
var(data$Income, "Income")
var(data$Marital1, "Marital1")
var(data$Children, "Children")
```

`var(data$Children, "Children")$diff` does not work here. I also takes a look at `str(var(data$Children, "Children"))`, still cannot figure out how to exact `diff` from the function. Ideally, I want to write code to give me the value of `diff` for each variable.

Comment: Have you tried adding `return(diff)` at the end of your function?

Comment: Remember to use `return(vdiff)` before closing the last `}` of the function if you want this vector as output.

Comment: I tried ```return(diff)``` at the end of the function. However, in this case, ggplot would not show up. Basically, I want the function to generate ggplot automatically. For ```diff```, I just want it to show up when I need it. For example, when I create a vector ```vdiff```, which consists of all ```diff```

Comment: Automatically when you run `ggplot` (without saving it into a variable name) it will appear in the screen of your computer. The function with `return(vdiff)` will also allow you to access to this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return diff in the end

```
var = function(dt, title){
  m=count(dt)
  vlist=list()
  for (i in (1:dim(m)[1])){
    m$"%Renew"[i]=sum(data$Renew==1 & dt ==m$x[i])/m$freq[i] *100
  }

  diff=max(m[,3]) - min(m[,3])
  vlist=list(table=m, difference = diff)

  print(ggplot(m, aes(x,m[,3])) + geom_point()+
          theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1), axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold")) +
          labs(x=title, y="% Renew") + ylim(0,100))
  return(diff)
}
```

then to get your vector, assuming dt is a data.frame:

```
cols <- c("Product", "Purchase","Type","Freq","Gender","State","Income","Marital1","Children")

vdiff <- sapply(cols,function(x){var(dt[,x],x)})
```

Also, var and diff are base R functions, it may be wise to choose other names.

Comment: `diff` is a base function as well. I think OP needs to return `vlist`. Using `x$diff` will partially match with `x$difference`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns `ggplot2` object. Consider returning some other object, like `return(vlist)`. You will be able to partially match values `difference` and `table` from your `vlist` variable.

Explicitly naming `return()` is not necessary if this is the last line of your function.

Comment: I want the ```ggplot2``` graph as well. actually, this function generates the ggplot graph automatically, that's what I want. Now, I want to extract variable ```diff``` as well. I tried to add ```return(diff)``` as the last line of the function. However, in this case, ggplot does not show up.

Comment: @user129343 In that case, try wrapping `ggplot2` call into a `print` statement.

Comment: Thank you very much! Both answers help solve my question. However, I am only allowed to choose one. Thank you again for your help!